# How to save a json object in variable in angular 9?

Tags: angular

I have this method and needed to save the result in a variable, but i am new in angular and have no clue how to do it. I have seen many videos and tutorials, but no success. I appreciate any help. Here is the code from the file. It is the component.ts file:

```html
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NavbarService } from "src/app/core/services/navbar.service";
import { QuotationSteps } from "./enums/quotation-steps.enum";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { QuotationProponentStepComponent } from './components/quotation-proponent-step/quotation-proponent-step.component';
import { Step } from 'src/app/core/models/step';

@Component({
  selector: "app-proposal",
  templateUrl: "./quotation.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./quotation.component.scss"],
})
export class QuotationComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @ViewChild(QuotationProponentStepComponent) basicProponentComponent: QuotationProponentStepComponent;

  currentStep: number = QuotationSteps.Proponent;
  proponent: any;
  assets: any[] = [];

  steps: Step[] = [
    {
      index: QuotationSteps.Proponent,
      label: 'Proponente'
    },
    {
      index: QuotationSteps.Assets,
      label: 'Cadastrar Bens'
    },
    {
      index: QuotationSteps.GenerateProposal,
      label: 'Gerar Proposta'
    },
    {
      index: QuotationSteps.Share,
      label: 'Compartilhar'
    },
  ]

  constructor(private navbarService: NavbarService, private router: Router) {
    this.navbarService.setContentTitle("Criar Cotação");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //pegar dados do local storage para fins de desenvolvimento
    if(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('assets')) == null){
      this.assets = [];
    }
    else{
      this.assets = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('assets'));
    }

  }

  public get QuotationSteps() {
    return QuotationSteps;
  }

  changeStep(event) {
    
    if (event.step >= 0) {
      // evento emitido pelo click no stepper
      if(this.currentStep == QuotationSteps.Proponent){
        this.basicProponentComponent.save();
      }

      this.currentStep = event.step;
      return;
    }

    if (event.goForward) {
      // evento emitido pelo botao proximo
      this.currentStep++;
      return;
    }

    // evento emitido pelo botao voltar

    if (this.currentStep == QuotationSteps.Proponent) {
      this.router.navigate(["../../app/comercial"]);
    } else {
      this.currentStep--;
      return;
    }
  }

  saveProponent(proponent){
    this.proponent = proponent;
    localStorage.setItem('proponent', JSON.stringify(proponent));
  }

  saveAsset(asset){
    asset.services = [];
    this.assets = [...this.assets, asset];    
    localStorage.setItem('assets', JSON.stringify(this.assets));
  }

  deleteAsset(asset){
    if(asset.serialNumber){
      this.assets = this.assets.filter(x => x.serialNumber !== asset.serialNumber);
      localStorage.setItem('assets', JSON.stringify(this.assets));
      return;
    }
    this.assets = this.assets.filter(x => x.licensePlate !== asset.licensePlate);
    localStorage.setItem('assets', JSON.stringify(this.assets));
    
  }

  editAsset(asset){

  }


}
```

This is the piece of the code i have to store in the variable. In fact i dont even know if i should do this in this file:

```html
saveProponent(proponent){
    this.proponent = proponent;
    localStorage.setItem('proponent', JSON.stringify(proponent));
  }
```

Comment: what did not work ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to cache the value of proponent? You can just use a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject), `proponentChange = new BehaviorSubject(null)`, to save the value `proponentChange .next(proponent)` & to retrieve it `var proponent = proponentChange.value`